# Creating a list of random vectors in R

Tags: r, random, vector

I am trying to create a list 1000 entries long where each entry of the list a random vector.  In this case the vector should be a 10 integers chosen from the integers 1 to 100. I want to avoid doing this in a loop.

If I run the following, this does not sample again, but just replicates the sample across all 1000 entries of the list:

```
list.of.samples <- rep(list(sample(1:100,size=10)),1000)
```

Is there an easy way that I am missing to vectorize the generation of these 1000 samples and store them in a list?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In cases like this, I often use the `replicate` function:

```
list.of.samples <- replicate(1000, sample(1:100,size=10), simplify=FALSE)
```

It repeatedly evaluates its second argument. Setting `simplify=FALSE` means you get back a list, not an array.

Answer (score 3):

`rep` will repeat whatever is given. `lapply` should do what you want.

```
list.of.samples = lapply(1:1000, function(x) sample(1:100,size=10))
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a vector with letters:

```
library(wakefield)
c = lower(10, k=3)   # generates 10 random letters from the first 3
c
#> "b" "a" "a" "a" "a" "b" "c" "b" "a" "b"
```